# Oscillations in voltage controlled current source

Tags: operational-amplifier

I'm trying to build a pulsed voltage controlled current source using an op-amp.  It has a tendency to oscillate (although sometimes to works okay, just often enough to give me hope that I might be close).

I'm looking to drive currents from 100 mA - 1A through a load which ranges from 12 Ω - 35 Ω.  I'm using an [LM675](http://www.ti.com/product/LM675) [(datasheet)](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm675.pdf) because I have it at hand, and it's rated for the voltage and current.  Vin is provided from a Labview-controlled DAQ.  The schematic is below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fT2yAB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The 1 Ω resistor and 0.22 uF cap from the examples on the LM675 data sheet.  I confess I don't understand stability all that well.

I've tried similar circuits with other op-amps and the past, and sometimes been sucessful, and other times encountered the same problem I have now.  I'd appreciate any advice.

Comment: 1. LM675 is not unity-gain stable. Depending on the load, this could be your problem. 2. Notwithstanding all the example circuits in the datasheet show the 1 ohm + 220 nF hanging from the output, capacitive loads can muck things up for most op-amps. Try removing the cap and see what happens.

Comment: LM675 is stable for gains 10+. With R_Load 12-35 ohm noise gain is in 3.5-8 range, so no way. Just try adding compensation network as Fig.12 in LM675 datasheet. But some extra info is needed: 1)Is load purely resistive or has any reactive component? 2)What about power supply decoupling? High output currents demand stiff supply.

Comment: The photon:  Without the 1 ohm +220nF off the output the circuit will always oscillate and worse than with them there.

Comment: carloc:  How do I calculate noise gain?  I suspected this was related to my problem, but I wasn't sure how to calculate gain for since it wasn't an amplifier.  I will try to network from Fig 12.  To answer your other questions: 1) The load is nearly resistive.  Its remote from the circuit and fed by about 2 ft of BNC cable, so there is a slight capacitance in parallel with it.  The load does have a high TCR, and its resistance does increase (but still stay within the 12-35 ohm range).  2)  I've got 20 uF between each supply and ground near the op amp.